# pip install hotqueue not working

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to run the following command to install hotqueue

```
sudo pip install hotqueue
```

But this does not seem to work. The following is the output this command generates on my computer.

```
The directory '/home/viraj_96/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please   check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/viraj_96/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting hotqueue
    Downloading hotqueue-0.2.7.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.14.tar.gz
Extracting in /tmp/tmptqdyx8b8
Now working in /tmp/tmptqdyx8b8/distribute-0.6.14
Building a Distribute egg in /tmp/pip-build-cz3_ivfm/hotqueue
creating build
creating build/src
creating build/src/docs
creating build/src/docs/_templates
creating build/src/docs/_theme
creating build/src/docs/_theme/nature
creating build/src/docs/_theme/nature/static
creating build/src/docs/build
creating build/src/docs/build/html
creating build/src/docs/build/html/_sources
creating build/src/docs/build/html/_static
creating build/src/setuptools
creating build/src/setuptools/command
creating build/src/setuptools/tests
creating build/src/setuptools/tests/indexes
creating build/src/setuptools/tests/indexes/test_links_priority
creating build/src/setuptools/tests/indexes/test_links_priority/simple
creating build/src/setuptools/tests/indexes/test_links_priority/simple/foobar
creating build/src/tests
creating build/src/tests/shlib_test
copying setuptools/depends.py -> build/src/setuptools
copying setuptools/archive_util.py -> build/src/setuptools
copying setuptools/package_index.py -> build/src/setuptools
copying setuptools/extension.py -> build/src/setuptools
copying setuptools/sandbox.py -> build/src/setuptools
copying setuptools/dist.py -> build/src/setuptools
copying setuptools/__init__.py -> build/src/setuptools
copying setuptools/tests/test_resources.py -> build/src/setuptools/tests
copying setuptools/tests/test_packageindex.py -> build/src/setuptools/tests
copying setuptools/tests/test_develop.py -> build/src/setuptools/tests
copying setuptools/tests/test_easy_install.py -> build/src/setuptools/tests
copying setuptools/tests/test_upload_docs.py -> build/src/setuptools/tests
copying setuptools/tests/doctest.py -> build/src/setuptools/tests
copying setuptools/tests/server.py -> build/src/setuptools/tests
copying setuptools/tests/test_build_ext.py -> build/src/setuptools/tests
copying setuptools/tests/test_sandbox.py -> build/src/setuptools/tests
copying setuptools/tests/__init__.py -> build/src/setuptools/tests
copying setuptools/command/develop.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/bdist_wininst.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/register.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/install_lib.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/test.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/rotate.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/upload_docs.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/upload.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/saveopts.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/easy_install.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/setopt.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/bdist_rpm.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/egg_info.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/alias.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/sdist.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/build_py.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/__init__.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/install_scripts.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/install_egg_info.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/install.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/command/build_ext.py -> build/src/setuptools/command
copying setuptools/tests/win_script_wrapper.txt -> build/src/setuptools/tests
copying setuptools/gui.exe -> build/src/setuptools
copying setuptools/cli.exe -> build/src/setuptools
copying tests/test_distribute_setup.py -> build/src/tests
copying tests/manual_test.py -> build/src/tests
copying tests/install_test.py -> build/src/tests
copying tests/shlib_test/setup.py -> build/src/tests/shlib_test
copying tests/shlib_test/test_hello.py -> build/src/tests/shlib_test
copying tests/shlib_test/hellolib.c -> build/src/tests/shlib_test
copying tests/shlib_test/hello.c -> build/src/tests/shlib_test
copying tests/shlib_test/hello.pyx -> build/src/tests/shlib_test
copying tests/api_tests.txt -> build/src/tests
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: buffer
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: idioms
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: set_literal
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
RefactoringTool: Skipping implicit fixer: ws_comma
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
RefactoringTool: Refactored build/src/tests/api_tests.txt
RefactoringTool: Files that were modified:
RefactoringTool: build/src/tests/api_tests.txt
--- build/src/tests/api_tests.txt   (original)
+++ build/src/tests/api_tests.txt   (refactored)
@@ -39,7 +39,7 @@
     >>> dist.py_version == sys.version[:3]
     True

-    >>> print dist.platform
+    >>> print(dist.platform)
     None

 Including various computed attributes::
@@ -199,7 +199,7 @@
 You can ask a WorkingSet to ``find()`` a distribution matching a requirement::

     >>> from pkg_resources import Requirement
-    >>> print ws.find(Requirement.parse("Foo==1.0"))    # no match, return None
+    >>> print(ws.find(Requirement.parse("Foo==1.0")))    # no match, return None
     None

     >>> ws.find(Requirement.parse("Bar==0.9"))  # match, return distribution
@@ -211,7 +211,7 @@
     >>> try:
     ...     ws.find(Requirement.parse("Bar==1.0"))
     ... except VersionConflict:
-    ...     print 'ok'
+    ...     print('ok')
     ok

 You can subscribe a callback function to receive notifications whenever a new
@@ -219,7 +219,7 @@
 once for each existing distribution in the working set, and then is called
 again for new distributions added thereafter::

-    >>> def added(dist): print "Added", dist
+    >>> def added(dist): print("Added", dist)
     >>> ws.subscribe(added)
     Added Bar 0.9
     >>> foo12 = Distribution(project_name="Foo", version="1.2", location="f12")
copying setuptools/tests/indexes/test_links_priority/external.html -> build/src/setuptools/tests/indexes/test_links_priority
copying setuptools/tests/indexes/test_links_priority/simple/foobar/index.html -> build/src/setuptools/tests/indexes/test_links_priority/simple/foobar
copying docs/conf.py -> build/src/docs
copying docs/python3.txt -> build/src/docs
copying docs/setuptools.txt -> build/src/docs
copying docs/index.txt -> build/src/docs
copying docs/roadmap.txt -> build/src/docs
copying docs/easy_install.txt -> build/src/docs
copying docs/pkg_resources.txt -> build/src/docs
copying docs/using.txt -> build/src/docs
copying docs/build/html/_sources/python3.txt -> build/src/docs/build/html/_sources
copying docs/build/html/_sources/setuptools.txt -> build/src/docs/build/html/_sources
copying docs/build/html/_sources/index.txt -> build/src/docs/build/html/_sources
copying docs/build/html/_sources/roadmap.txt -> build/src/docs/build/html/_sources
copying docs/build/html/_sources/easy_install.txt -> build/src/docs/build/html/_sources
copying docs/build/html/_sources/pkg_resources.txt -> build/src/docs/build/html/_sources
copying docs/build/html/_sources/using.txt -> build/src/docs/build/html/_sources
copying docs/_theme/nature/theme.conf -> build/src/docs/_theme/nature
copying docs/build/html/_static/pygments.css -> build/src/docs/build/html/_static
copying docs/build/html/_static/nature.css -> build/src/docs/build/html/_static
copying docs/build/html/_static/basic.css -> build/src/docs/build/html/_static
copying docs/_theme/nature/static/pygments.css -> build/src/docs/_theme/nature/static
copying docs/_theme/nature/static/nature.css_t -> build/src/docs/_theme/nature/static
copying docs/Makefile -> build/src/docs
copying docs/_templates/indexsidebar.html -> build/src/docs/_templates
copying setup.py -> build/src
copying easy_install.py -> build/src
copying distribute_setup.py -> build/src
copying pkg_resources.py -> build/src
copying site.py -> build/src
copying DEVGUIDE.txt -> build/src
copying CHANGES.txt -> build/src
copying CONTRIBUTORS.txt -> build/src
copying README.txt -> build/src
copying MANIFEST.in -> build/src
copying launcher.c -> build/src
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
Skipping implicit fixer: buffer
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
Skipping implicit fixer: idioms
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
Skipping implicit fixer: set_literal
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
Skipping implicit fixer: ws_comma
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
root: Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.4/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'entry_points'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: invalid command 'bdist_egg'
/tmp/pip-build-cz3_ivfm/hotqueue/distribute-0.6.14-py3.4.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pip-build-cz3_ivfm/hotqueue/distribute_setup.py", line 143, in use_setuptools
    raise ImportError
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-cz3_ivfm/hotqueue/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    from distribute_setup import use_setuptools; use_setuptools()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-cz3_ivfm/hotqueue/distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-cz3_ivfm/hotqueue/distribute_setup.py", line 125, in _do_download
    _build_egg(egg, tarball, to_dir)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-cz3_ivfm/hotqueue/distribute_setup.py", line 116, in _build_egg
    raise IOError('Could not build the egg.')
OSError: Could not build the egg.

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-cz3_ivfm/hotqueue/
```

I dont know what's the error. Some googling told me that the error might be that setup.py is using distutils and not setuptools or that setuptools is not updated. I  tried updating setuptools but still no progress. I dont know the exact reason as to why it is not working. It's the only library thats bugging me while other libraries install quite easily with pip.

Comment: Why did you tag this `python-2.7` if you're trying to install it on Python 3.4? What is this lib anyway? It hasn't been updated since 2012 and there are plenty of other ways to use redis from Python.

Comment: Sorry for that tag error. It has been edited. As the repo mentions "HotQueue is a Python library that allows you to use Redis as a message queue within your Python programs." Its not that I want to use it, it has been used in a different codebase which is under contruction since 2012 or 2011. It's just to meet some dependencies of that codebase.

Comment: I do not think that library works on Python 3 is what I'm getting at.

Comment: I tried installing `hotqueue` and found out that installation works for Python 2.7 but not for Python 3.5. Perhaps you should consider using Python 2.7 if this package is essential to your project.